# Why Inertia render not working on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, firefox, inertiajs

I have made a website with Laravel and Inertia Js, but when it is in production it doesn't render the components when browsing, only if it is entered directly from the url.

When navigating using the inertia-link tag the site returns:

`All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received.`

This only happens in Firefox

[image]

Comment: I looked at the Inertia source code for this error message and the fact that this is only happening on Firefox got me think that this is probably a bug. I would recommend that you open an Issue on Inertia's Github repository here: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia